# How does port forwarding work as it pertains to bandwidth usage

Tags: port-forwarding, bandwidth

Let's say there are two servers: Server A with a 500mbps of available bandwidth and Server B with 1gbps of available bandwidth(same vendor). If there are a port forwarding configured on Server A pointing to Server B then would users use Server A bandwidth or Server B bandwidth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would use both server's bandwidth, but the smallest link would be the bottleneck, assuming there are no other issues.